# How to fill a column with values based on other column's values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. record |  |  |
| att1 |  |  |
| att2 | value1 | value2 |
| 2. record |  |  |
| att3 | value1 | value2 |
| 3. record |  |  |
| att4 | value1 |  |
| att5 | value1 | value2 |

The desired output would be:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. record |  |  | 1. record |
| att1 |  |  | 1. record |
| att2 | value1 | value2 | 1. record |
| 2. record |  |  | 2. record |
| att3 | value1 | value2 | 2. record |
| 3. record |  |  | 3. record |
| att4 | value1 |  | 3. record |
| att5 | value1 | value2 | 3. record |

The problem is it cannot be hard-coded because I don't know how many records and attributes will be there beforehand. Important addition is that the records and attributes are strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried a for loop with str.contains() if-else statements, but it didn't work out really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is important condition - e.g. here is use `df['col1'].str.contains('^\d')` for replace `col1` values starting by number and then forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
df['col4'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].str.contains('^\d')).ffill()
print (df)
        col1    col2    col3       col4
0  1. record                  1. record
1       att1                  1. record
2       att2  value1  value2  1. record
3  2. record                  2. record
4       att3  value1  value2  2. record
5  3. record                  3. record
6       att4  value1          3. record
7       att5  value1  value2  3. record
```

Or test `record`:

```
df['col4'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].str.contains('record')).ffill()
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! A question just came to my mind, what if any attribute starts with a number also in col1 ?

Comment: @trefa - Hmmm, then it failed. I think condition depends of data, so added to possible masks, but if failed is necessary specified how is possible distingush values for groups from another vals?

Comment: @anik jha - From changed data is not possible match by empty strings in both `col2, col3`, because it failed for firt group.

Comment: @ jezrael Thank you, the 'record' one answered my question, I have just changed the regex for `^[1-9][0-9]?\.|record$`